# LEAST with 'if' condition brings timestamp instead of date

Tags: mariadb

I was testing some new code in my server 1 and everything was just fine. When I sent my code to my server2 [Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)] , which is almost the same as server1 [Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)], something went wrong.

The query was like :

```
select alpha, beta, gama, if(condition,alpha, beta) as aux1, least(if(condition,alpha, beta),gamma) as aux2 from table where field1='foo';
```

The fields alpha,beta and gamma are dates (YYYY-MM-DD), and the 'condition' doesn't matter, there was a problem either being true or false. The output in the server2 had a timestamp instead of a date in one of the fields:

```
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| alpha      | beta          | gamma          | aux1            | aux2                 |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-02    | 2013-01-02     | 2013-01-02      | 2013-01-02  00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

So I ran some test to isolate the problem:

```
select alpha, beta, gama, if(condition,alpha, beta) as aux1, least(alpha,gamma) as aux2 from table where field1='foo';
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| alpha      | beta          | gamma          | aux1            | aux2                 |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-02    | 2013-01-02     | 2013-01-02      | 2013-01-02           |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
select alpha, beta, gama, if(condition,alpha, beta) as aux1, least(beta,gamma) as aux2 from table where field1='foo';
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| alpha      | beta          | gamma          | aux1            | aux2                 |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-02    | 2013-01-02     | 2013-01-02      | 2013-01-02           |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

So it seems the problem occurs when I use LEAST with a IF condition when looking for date fields.

I can use a SUBSTRING to handle it, but I would like to know if this was an intentional behavior and if I can detour it some other way.

Comment: You can probably use `date()` instead of substring as a workaround. If you already have this test case, could you please report it? There seems to be a similar report for [5.5.49](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9972) so either comment on that one or create a new one for 10.0.22 and reference that.

Comment: @jkavalik Thank you, I saw that you reported the bug there. I was kind of busy these days...

Comment: Hope you don't mind. The bug seems to be "fixed" now so it might be released with the new version hopefully?

Comment: Just to let you know, I updated to `10.0.26` and the test case from [MDEV-9521](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9521) now returns `date` properly.